# Differences in column values between 2 two identical table structures

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle Database: I have a table which is kept in sync with data from an external system. Every 15 minutes, we get a feed of any changes to this master table. We can store this feed of modified records in a staging table. We need to find the columns that have changed between the master and the staging table and record these differences for a subsequent processing.

Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE Master
(
 Id int NOT NULL,
 LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 FirstName varchar(255),
 CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

Now, I have a Stage table that has exactly the same structure. In this simple example, I can do a diff between the Master and Stage like so:

```
  select decode( a.FirstName, b.FirstName, 0, 1 ) firstname_changed,
  decode( a.LastName, b.LastName, 0, 1 ) lastname_changed
  from Stage a, Master b
  where a.Id = b.Id;
```

Now the problem is that the master table contains 145 columns. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Change data capture?   [Click me!](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm)

Comment: Put insert and update queries into a stored procedure.  The bad news is that there will be a lot of typing.  The good news is that you will only have to do all that typing once.

Comment: select * from stage minus select * from master

Comment: @Andrew, CDC would have been perfect. I need to test if the column_list in the subscribe call works to notify only if those columns got updated versus if the row got updated. The bigger problem is that 11.2 docs mention -> the Oracle Change Data Capture will be de-supported in a future release of Oracle Database and will be replaced with Oracle GoldenGate.

Comment: @Glenn, MINUS would tell me the differing rows between master and stage. I need to record the columns that have been modified.

Comment: So the feed is only for rows that have changed?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, the feed should be for changed rows only. We could then compare these rows against our version of the master to determine the column changes before merging the changes in.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Set Operations In Oracle

UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators

[refer oracle doc link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

Comment: Problem is these are row level operations. For ex, MINUS would tell you the differing rows.

Answer (score 0):

One common method is to calculate a hash value for every row of the table as part of the insert or update to it (using a trigger perhaps) on all of the columns that you want to detect changes on. Do the same as part of reading the new data and you can ...

```
select t.id,
       case t.hash_value when s.hash_value then 'N' else 'Y' end changed
from   source_table s join target_table t on s.id = t.id.
```

This allows the query to use a much smaller hash table as part of the join as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could load your set of changed rows into a table.  Then compare them to the existing table, and just update the whole row.

```
Something like:
update <PermanentTable> p
(big giant column list)
as 
select <another big giant column list>
from <yourTempTable> t
where
t.<uniqueIdentifier = p.uniqueIdentifier
```

It would still make for a boatload of typing, but you could save the script.

Or maybe you could do something like

```
delete from <PermanentTable> p
inner join <yourTempTable> t
on p.uniqueid = t.uniqueid
```

And then just insert all the rows from your staging table.

Or maybe you could chuck the whole manual CDC thing, and just replicate the source table?